# Largest singular value of a normalised frequency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be an $n \times m$ matrix of non-negative integers where $n \ge m$. Define $P$ to be the matrix with $(i,j)$ entry $\frac{X_{ij}}{\sum X_{ij}}$, where the summation is over all entries of $X$. Define $r$ to be the length $n$ vector with $i$th entry $\sum_{j=1}^{m} X_{ij}$ and define $c$ to be the length $m$ vector with $i$th entry $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{ij}$.

Finally, define $Y$ to be the $n \times m$ matrix with $(i,j)$ entry $\frac{P_{ij}}{\sqrt{r_i c_j}}$. Is $Y$'s largest singular value $1$? Can someone please give me a hint.

Comment: Maybe it helps that the largest singular value $\sigma_{max}(A)$ of a matrix $A$ is the same as the spectral norm $\|A\|_2$ of that matrix, and that can be characterized by $\|A\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1\|_2} |y^T A x|$.

Comment: Is it too optimistic to try and find some inequality involving the operator norm and use it to show that the operator norm is less than or equal to 1 then show that the bound is attained?

Comment: Sounds like a sensible approach to me. I would give it a try myself, but don't have the time currently. BTW: before trying to prove something like this, I would always try some examples, maybe writing some code that computes the singular values for some random matrices. I did that in Python, and it turned out that $X_{ij}/\sqrt{r_i c_j}$ always attains largest singular value 1 (and not $P_{ij}/\sqrt{r_i c_j}$).